# Search inside a DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, search, datagrid

I have been fighting with some code I wrote in the past and trying to tweak it. Currently my search only searches for a matching first character of a word. I need to search more in depth. For instance if I search for planet in this string:

`"Earth is a planet"`

I get nothing, but if I search for planet in this next string:

`"Planet earth is amazing"`

I get the data grid to show just that line.

I want to be able to search for a word the shows the line regardless of whether its in the beginning of a string or end of one.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
import fl.controls.DataGrid;
import fl.controls.TextInput;
import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
import fl.data.DataProvider;

var voddb:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
voddb.addItem({title:"Earth is a planet", detail:"ALE 0110"});
voddb.addItem({title:"Planet Earth", detail:"ALE 0210"});
voddb.addItem({title:"Jupiter is a planet", detail:"ALE 0310"});
voddb.addItem({title:"Aplanet Jupiter", detail:"ALE 0410"});
voddb.addItem({title:"Another amazing planet is mars", detail:"ALE 0510"});
voddb.addItem({title:"Planets include earth and mars:", detail: "ALE      0610"});

vodTextInput.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

var titleCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("title");
titleCol.headerText = "Title";

var detailCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("detail");
detailCol.headerText = "Details";
detailCol.sortOptions = Array.DESCENDING;

vodDataGrid.addColumn(titleCol);
vodDataGrid.addColumn(detailCol);
vodDataGrid.dataProvider = voddb;

function changeHandler(event : Event) : void 
{
    var arr : Array          = voddb.toArray();
    var filteredArr : Array  = arr.filter(filterDataProvider);
    vodDataGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(filteredArr);
}
function filterDataProvider(obj : Object, idx : String, arr : Array) : Boolean 
{
    var txt1 : String = vodTextInput.text;
    var txt2 : String = obj.title.substr(0, txt1.length);

    if (txt1.toLowerCase() == txt2.toLowerCase())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add I know its the  var txt2:String = obj.title.substr(0, txt1.length); part that I can't figure out. Tried splice etc to no avail.

Comment: For future reference, instead of saying `if (txt1.toLowerCase() == txt2.toLowerCase()) { return true; } else { return false; }` You can just say `return txt1.toLowerCase() == txt2.toLowerCase();` and it will have the exact same affect

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` to search for the string.

```
function filterDataProvider(obj : Object, idx : int, arr : Array) : Boolean 
{
    var txt1 : String = vodTextInput.text.toLowerCase();
    var txt2 : String = obj.title.toLowerCase();
    return txt2.indexOf(txt1) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.